# How could I make a normal human character who has no powers, weapons, or tech defeat someone who is superhuman?

Tags: super-powers, fight

I am writing a story about an average 200 pound guy who is being attacked by someone who has super strength (can lift 6000 tons), "instinct cancellation" (which is just the nullification of instinctive combat), mind reading (any thoughts are read, so he can't think), super speed (40,000 miles per hour), and near invincibility (needs 50,000 joules to even damage the villain). it is imperative for the 200 pound guy to prevail, because the "average joes" are oppressed by the superhumans, and this is intended to start a revolution. How to I do this in a way that is not something along the lines of "an asteroid fell from space onto them" or "a fissure in the ground opened up and made them fall through?"

Comment: This looks like a story problem not a worldbuilding problem.

Comment: @sphennings I think it is worldbuilding... I am trying to figure out a way that, in a parallel world, the main hero could fight said superhuman.

Comment: You've painted yourself into a corner here.  You've built your world to make the superhero impossible to beat, and now you need someone to beat him.  Might be time to back up a good way on plotting.

Comment: The problem here is that your superhuman is too strong to be beaten without any preparation. If memories of a future past have something to show is that humans don't beat threats by using bulk, they use their brains to build something that has the necessary bulk to beat the threat. This is kind of one of the reasons in many stories supers aren't the absolute majority of the population, or the "normal" people stop being the "normies" to become the "weaklings"/"squishies" /"[insert derogatory name that alludes to a weaker nature]".

Comment: The comments can be mean here, but the main gist of why the question was closed is: your question is about  something related to your world, but rather than being about a problem about the world itself and/or how it works (example: what needs to be different in your superhuman so that they can lift an 6 kilotons), it was more centered about a story happening in the world (how can the normal guy win in a fight). Making the tour and checking the help center would be a good idea. Welcome to world building SE. Sorry for the bumpy start.

Comment: Lack of research. Check out [Achilles' Heel](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AchillesHeel) (TV Tropes warning).

Comment: The problem with evolution is that someone like this super person would have evolved only because of being prey to something else. So, there are a number of ways this person could be killed. For example, bacteria and viruses are still very lethal. Individual strength evolves because they can't work with others. Pack action can take them down. They are vulnerable when they sleep. They can be lured into quicksand, thin ice over frozen lakes, or other places where trying to use strength will work against them.

Comment: Every strength has a place where it is a weakness. For example, mind reading works one on one. But in a crowd, it can drive a person mad. Surround a mind reader with a group of people with delusions and Dali paintings and watch him go mad. Lift 5000 pounds? That works only when what the person is standing on can support that weight. Try to do that on a raft at sea.

Comment: In an asymmetrical war, take asymmetrical losses and focus on the long haul. Out breed and prevent him from having children. Or focus on the food and water and starve him out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They say God made man, but Samuel Colt made them equal.

...then the superhumans arrived.

Fortunately, the modern military industrial complex stepped in to restore the balance.

They say God made man, but Robert Oppenheimer made them glowing ashes.

Give the normal joe a briefcase nuclear bomb with the detonator wired to its lock.  Tell normal joe that the box contains a bribe for the superhuman and ask him to deliver it.

Nuke the Sup!

Comment: I *fully* support the "nuke them from orbit" approach to insurmountable problem. Except what OP seems to described is the Joe being attacked by AngryClarkKent, so nuking him would also means being in proximity to the nuke. Last time I tried that in Fallout, they found bits of me all across Nevada. Nuke isn't great in close quarters imo, so it's a situationnal weapon/answer, no?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why we ask to answer only well asked questions... OP is new, gets told the question has problem, grabs the first answer and flies away...

Comment: @Nyakouai OP didn't request that the mechanism of victory be survivable for the non-super.

Comment: @LDutch, you are absolutely right and I apologize for being the trouble maker this time.  I should have waited, but I really liked the Samuel Colt vs Oppenheimer word play.  Sorry!

Comment: @L.Dutch There is another possibility, too. A new contributor gets discouraged by mean comments and decides that WB.SE is not the type of community they would want to be a part of. So they leave. But being a nice person they accept the only posted answer just to give points to the non-mean person who took time and effort to answer their question. You are a moderator. It might've been better to refrain from judgemental comments about people you do not know.